# How to remove the insignificant whitespace in a XmlNodeType.Text node?

Tags: c#, html, xml, whitespace

I have an html node:

```
<p>Line1
Line2
Line
ThereAreTwoSpacesAfterThis  ThereAreTwoSpacesBeforeThis
</p>
```

In any browser, the final use result is

```
Line1 Line2 Line ThereAreTwoSpacesAfterThis ThereAreTwoSpacesBeforeThis
```

which is the result I want.

So how to remove the insignificant whitespace in a XmlNodeType.Text node (C#)?

=========================================================

Hi guys, Thanks for your reply.

Actually I'm working on a small project to extract all the text from a web page (html): something like "Save As page as text file" from Firefox or IE.

I tried to use Html Agility Pack, but the result is not good enough.

I also tried to use a WebBrowser control, but it seems too slow, and it's kind of not so easy to control over it.

Any good ideas?

I understand that guys suggest me to use regex, but there are too many cases to think about.

Comment: Whoa, big fat shifting requirements. Your question was initially *only* about text inside a `p` tag and *only* about removing whitespace. Now you’re asking how to *render an entire HTML page in plain-text*?! Presumably you also want it to correctly interpret the CSS `white-space` property, which controls white-space collapsing, on every element? You’re on the first step to writing a fullblown HTML rendering engine.

Comment: You are right.  Sorry for the confusion.  I googled and searched a lot about converting html to plain text, but no luck.  All I got is to use Html Agility Pack, which does not work enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just use a regular expression!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-programming-quote/205#205)

```
var spacesSquashed = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If you also want to remove all spaces at the beginning and end, as is customary in HTML, add an extra `.Trim()` at the end.

Comment: Tempted to upvote because you included that quote :) For this specific usage I guess regex is okay...